# ¿Comó refrescar tabla con AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, html5

tengo un problema para recargar una tabla en html con AJAX a la hora de activar y/o desactivar una sección mi objetivo es que se vea el cambio en tiempo real y lo que sucede es que tengo que recargar la página manualmente para que se refleje el cambió realizado, estuve investigando y encontré que tenia que hacer uso de un div pero aún utilizando el div no logro obtener ese efecto.
Adjunto mi código:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive mt-1" id="secciones">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">ORDENAR</th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="col">SECCIÓN</th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="col">TEXTO</th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="col">ESTATUS</th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="col">ACCIÓN</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    $id=1; 
                    foreach ($registros as $registro):?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sort"></i></a></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><b><?php echo $registro['nombre_seccion'];?></b></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><b><?php echo $registro['texto'];?></b></td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <a href="#" class="cambiaEstatus <?php echo($registro['status']!=1) ? "toggle-off" : "visible";?>" data-id="<?php echo $id;?>" title="Cambiar Estatus" alt="Cambiar Estatus">
                            <i class="fas fa-toggle-on"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <a href="edita_seccion.php?id=<?php echo $registro['id_seccion'];?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark">Editar Sección</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    $id++; 
                    endforeach;?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
$id_estatus = $_GET['idchange'];

$sql_seccion_estatus = "SELECT * FROM seccion WHERE id_seccion='$id_estatus'";

$obtener_estatus = obtenerEstatus($sql_seccion_estatus, $conecta);

if (!empty($id_estatus) && $obtener_estatus == 1)
{
   $sql_inactivo = "UPDATE seccion SET status='0' WHERE id_seccion='$id_estatus'";

    $cambio_inactivo = modificaRegistro($sql_inactivo, $conecta);

    echo ($cambio_inactivo!=false) ? "Sección Desactivada" : "";

    die();

 }elseif(!empty($id_estatus) && $obtener_estatus == 0) 
 {
    $sql_activo = "UPDATE seccion SET status='1' WHERE id_seccion='$id_estatus'";

    $cambio_activo = modificaRegistro($sql_activo, $conecta);

     echo ($cambio_activo !=false) ? "Sección Activada" : "";

     die();
  }
  require 'views/secciones.view.php';
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   editaSeccion();
});

function editaSeccion()
{
  $(".cambiaEstatus").on("click", function(event) 
   {
      event.preventDefault();
      var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
      console.log(id);
      $.get("secciones.php", "idchange="+id, function(respuesta)
      {
         console.log(respuesta);
         if (respuesta == "Sección Desactivada")
         {
            alertify.error(respuesta);
         }else if (respuesta == "Sección Activada") 
         {
            alertify.success(respuesta);
         }
         cargarTabla();
      });
  });
}

function cargarTabla()
{
   $.get("secciones.php", "", function(respuesta)
   {
      console.log(respuesta);
      $("#secciones").html(respuesta);
   });
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: No entiendo por qué tienes dos llamadas a `secciones.php`  ¿?  en el `onclick` y luego desde ese bloque llamas a `cargarTabla()`... me pregunto ¿para qué?.  ¿Esa primera llamada no te trae lo que necesitas? ¿Por qué mandas otra petición al servidor desde `cargarTabla()`. El error parece más de lógica y de organización de código que de otra cosa. Prueba a trasladar esto a la 1ª llamada: `$("#secciones").html(respuesta);`  y comenta la llamada que haces a `cargarTabla()`. Debería funcionar bien así.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta realizando la peticion AJAX de la siguiente Forma

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "GET", 
         url: "secciones.php",
         async: true, 
         data: { 'idchange': id},
         success: function(respuesta){
                 console.log(respuesta);
                 if (respuesta == "Sección Desactivada")
                 {
                     alertify.error(respuesta);
                 }else if (respuesta == "Sección Activada") 
                 {
                     alertify.success(respuesta);
                 }
                 cargarTabla();
         }
         error: function (request, error) {
                    alertify.success(error);
         }
   });

function cargarTabla()
{
    $.ajax({
         type: "GET", 
         url: "secciones.php",
         async: true, 
         success: function(respuesta){
                 $("#secciones").html("");
                 console.log(respuesta);
                 $("#secciones").html(respuesta);
         }
         error: function (request, error) {
                    alertify.success(error);
         }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para refrescar el contenido de la tabla debes usar la opciones `success` o `error` segun corresponda y cambiar el contenido usando `innertText`.

Para este caso realiza los cambios cuando entra en el `success` tanto el nuevo estado como el nuevo texto.

> Omito el codigo en PHP para poder implementar una prueba funcional en este post, la url puede ser cambiada por el archivo php y los parametros que requiera segun el caso.

```js
function activar(elemento, id) {
  let estado = elemento.innerText;
  elemento.innerText = "Cambiando..."
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET", 
     url: "https://httpbin.org/get?id="+id,
     async: true, 
     success: function(respuesta){
        elemento.innerText = estado == "Activar" ? "Desactivar" : "Activar" 
     },
     error: function (request, error) {
        elemento.innerText = "Error"
     }
  })
}

var tdCambiar;
var idCambiar;

function cambiar(elemento, id){
  tdCambiar = elemento;
  idCambiar = id;
  texto.value = elemento.innerText;
}

function guardarCambio(){
  let nuevo = texto.value  
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET", 
     url: "https://httpbin.org/get?id="+idCambiar+"&nuevo="+nuevo,
     async: true, 
     success: function(respuesta){
        texto.value = ""
        tdCambiar.innerText = respuesta.args.nuevo
        tdCambiar = null
     },
     error: function (request, error) {
        texto.innerText = "Error"
     }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
<th>Texto</th>
<th>Estado</th>
</thead>
<tr>
 <td onclick="cambiar(this,1)">Click Para Cambiar, Luego Guardar</td>
 <td><button onclick="activar(this, 1)">Activar</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<div >
 <input id="texto">
 <button onclick="guardarCambio()">Guardar</button>
</div>
```